# Realm Predicate for Membership in List

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, realm

I am trying to use [RealmGridController](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmGridController) to display elements in a relationship list. I have an object `Collection` that has a list of `Items`:

```
class Collection: Object {
    let items = List<Item>()

    dynamic var name: String?
}

class Item: Object {
    dynamic var name: String?
}
```

I would like to use a [RealmGridController](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmGridController) to show all of the items in the `items` property of a specific `collection`. [RealmGridController](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmGridController) uses [RBQFetchedResultsController](https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController) to manage its data loading, and the fetched results controller uses an entity name and a predicate to fetch the list of items to show.

**How can I express the list of items in a relationship `List` as an entity name and predicate?**

A few things I've tried that haven't worked:

```
entityName = Item.className()

// 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Predicate with IN operator must compare a KeyPath with an aggregate'
basePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF in %@.items", collection)
// Same
basePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF in %@", collection.items)
// 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Predicate with ANY modifier must compare a KeyPath with RLMArray with a value'
basePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY SELF in %@", collection.items)
```

It seems like displaying a Realm `List<>` as the contents of a fetched results controller should be fairly straightforward but I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RBQFetchedResultsController` doesn't support using a `List` as the data source. I spent some time working on this to explore using KVO to manage the notifications vs. `RBQRealmNotificationManager` but never finished it.

For now, I would suggest looking into Realm's new collection notification support added in [v0.98.0](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.98.0/). You can register to receive a notification when any object in the `List` is updated. This still doesn't offer the index change information, but this is coming soon.